# Why is strict exogeneity an assumption of OLS when it follows as a consequence?

Tags: regression, exogeneity

Strict exogeneity is generally listed as an assumption for OLS, i.e., $E[\epsilon\ |\ X]=0$. But then if I take the minimum mean squared error estimate of $Y$, i.e. $\hat Y=E[X\ |\ Y]$

$$E[\epsilon\ |\ X]=E[Y-\hat Y\ |\ X]=E[Y\ |\ X]-E[\hat Y\ |\ X]=\hat Y-E[\hat Y\ |\ X]=\hat Y-\hat Y=0$$ where the last equality follows because $\hat Y$ is a function of $X$, so $E[\hat Y\ |\ X]=\hat Y$.

(Above argument adapted from Lemma 9.1 in https://www.probabilitycourse.com/chapter9/9_1_5_mean_squared_error_MSE.php)

So doesn't strict exogeneity follow as a consequence rather as an assumption? What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're mixing up the unobserved errors with the residuals. The errors are $\epsilon = Y - X\beta$ but we never know them exactly since $\beta$ is unobserved. It is indeed an assumption that the errors have mean zero since having unobserved errors with a nonzero mean is certainly possible.

Your proof is more about showing that the residuals $e = Y - \hat Y$ have an expectation of zero although some of the steps in the middle aren't correct. In particular, $\text E[Y\mid X] = X\beta$, not $\hat Y$ which is still a function of $Y$. This comes from the very assumption in question:
$$
\text E[Y\mid X] = \text E[X\beta + \epsilon \mid X] = X\beta + \text E[\epsilon\mid X] = X\beta.
$$

A fixed version of the proof is this:
$$
\text E[e\mid X] =  \text E[Y - \hat Y\mid X] = \text E[Y\mid X] - \text E[\hat Y\mid X] = X\beta - X\,\text E[\hat \beta\mid X] = \mathbf 0
$$
assuming the necessary conditions for $\hat\beta$ to be unbiased.

Comment: Thank you so much! A couple of points of confusion: $\hat\beta$ is a parameter instead of a random variable per my understanding. So what RV is $\hat\beta$ trying to estimate and when would we call it unbiased? Secondly you mentioned that $E[Y\ |\ X]$ is not $\hat Y$ - that's confusing to me because it's at odds with the first box and Lemma 9.1's wording on this page: https://www.probabilitycourse.com/chapter9/9_1_5_mean_squared_error_MSE.php

Comment: @user9343456 I'm assuming we have $Y =X\beta + \epsilon$ with $\beta$ nonrandom and unknown, $\text E[\epsilon\mid X] = \mathbf 0$, and $\text {Var}[\epsilon\mid X] = \sigma^2 I$. If $X$ is full column rank then $\hat \beta = (X^TX)^{-1}X^TY$ which is random due to being a linear transformation of $Y$ (and also possibly from randomness in $X$). Under strict exogeneity we have $\text E[\hat\beta\mid X] = (X^TX)^{-1}X^TX\beta = \beta$ so $\hat\beta$ is unbiased, conditioned on $X$. $\hat\beta$ is an RV that is approximating the constant $\beta$.

Comment: @user9343456 for your second question, $\text E[Y\mid X]$ is a population quantity that we never actually observe, and it is equal to $X\beta$. We model $\text E[Y\mid X]$ as a linear function of $X$ and then the estimate is $X\hat\beta = \hat Y$. Does that help?

Comment: Thanks again. In the reference I linked to however, it does say $\hat Y=E[Y\ |\ X]$ (if you see the box). So the reasoning given is that this is a function of $X$ (say $g(X)$) and so $E[\hat Y\ |\ X]=E[g(X)\ |\ X]=g(X)$. BUT at that point in that course, the author hasn't talked about the LINEAR minimum mean squared error estimate. That comes later. So then your answer helps me understand the distinction between $e$ and $\epsilon$ (which solves my confusion). Just one thing if you don't mind: the proof of $E[e\ |\ X]$ given in that link (which my question follows) : is it correct?

Comment: @user9343456 re: $\hat Y$, I think we're talking about slightly different things. It's definitely true that the random variable $\text E[Y\mid X]$ is the best approximator of $Y$ in the squared loss sense (subject to a measurability constraint and ignoring almost sure equivalence). So in that sense we can think of $\text E[Y\mid X]$ as an estimator of $Y$. But in practice this is still a population quantity that we never observe, so we model $\text E[Y\mid X]$ as something simpler, in this case a linear function of $X$, and then we can use data to estimate _that_

Comment: @user9343456 for the proof on that site, i only did a quick skim but it looks correct to me

Comment: One last doubt (sorry to bug you so much - you don't have to answer this if it's a pain, have already marked your answer as accepted). If we have assumed $Y=X\beta + c + \epsilon$. Then we'd have to show that the estimator $\hat Y=X\hat\beta + \hat c$ is unbiased (minimal variance of that estimator follows from Gauss-Markov theorem). To show unbiased, we'd have to show $E[Y]=E[X\hat\beta+\hat c]$, i.e., $E[e]=0$ which follows only if we assume $\beta,c$ are derived by minimizing MSE. Is there any purpose of showing that $E[e\ |\ X]=0$?

Comment: @user9343456 no worries about the number of questions! For unbiasedness we have $\text E[\hat Y \mid X] = X \,\text E[\hat\beta\mid X] + \text E[\hat c\mid X]$ so it's determined by whether or not our parameter estimates are unbiased. If they are, then $\text E[\hat Y\mid X] = X\,\text E[\hat\beta\mid X] + \text E[\hat c\mid X] = X\beta + c = \text E[Y\mid X]$ since $\text E[\epsilon \mid X] = 0$. The errors having mean zero is closely related to $\hat\beta$ being unbiased. Does that help?